# Iphone : is there a way to force ADBanner displaying an Ad?

Tags: iphone, iad

Dear all,
I'm quite new in app development. Anyway, i learn...

So at this time, as i'm trying to use ADBanner, i wonder if there is a way to force a ADBannerView to display an ad ?

I want the user to clic the ad at a certain time, but if at this particular instant the ad is not displayed in the banner my app will certainly lost chance to be used ...

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Smaz

(sorry for my english which is not my native language)

Answer (score 0):

no friend you cannot control this . The time it is not uploaded to app store it shows ad banner running successfully and after upload to app store it shows ad's

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't control it. However, the better way is to hide the banner until there is no Ad in it. For the purpose you need to handle [delegate methods of the iAdView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

Hide the banner in `viewDidLoad` then show it in `bannerViewDidLoadAd` delegate method.

```
// Called when a new banner advertisement is loaded
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner;

// Called when a banner view fails to load a new advertisement
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner
    didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
```